# why search functionality is on separate screen rather than on same screen in apps?

Tags: android, search, screen, mobile-application

I am bit confused and i could not find answer to my question. Almost all the mobile application try to take us to different page or screen when we try to search. Can anybody explain me the philosophy behind taking user to a new screen on search rather searching on same screen and refreshing data? 
 Any links or examples to clear my doubt would really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Android Provides a SearchInterface which helps a developer to easily integrate search functionalities and for that you have to create a SearchableActivity that is why everyone uses a different activity for that,

more info at https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: not convinced  with your answer need philosophy behind it